# Proximity sensor ane for iOS

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have question about proximity-sensor-ane.

https://github.com/richardolsson/proximity-sensor-ane

When I use proximity-sensor-ane, thread is stop in flash side.

For example:

`flash.utils.Timer` class is not running when calling proximity-sensor-ane.

Also, I tried to change code:

```
[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode NSDefaultRunLoopMode]
            ↓
[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode NSRunLoopCommonModes]
```

It does not work..

Do you have any idea? Is it in the specification for iOS?

Comment: Two things: Could you post how you are attempting to run this? And this ANE is 2 years old. iOS APIs tend to change at about that rate. Are you sure the ANE supports iOS 7 (or whatever version you are running)?

Comment: thank you for comment. yes you right. this ANE is 2 years old. i will have to find other ANE...